# get jquery image width and add class

Tags: php, jquery, css, height, width

I'm having trouble getting the dimensions of a series of images that are loading via PHP.

```
<?
    $Ldir="imgs/liveGallery/"; // Directory where files are stored

    if ($Lhandle = opendir($Ldir)) {
        while (false !== ($Lfile = readdir($Lhandle))) {
            if ($Lfile != "." && $Lfile != "..") $Lthefiles[] = $Lfile;
        }
        closedir($Lhandle);
    }

    sort($Lthefiles);

    for ($Li=0;$Li<count($Lthefiles);$Li++) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $Ldir.$Lthefiles[$Li]; ?>" class="ilightbox">
                <div class="adj">
                    <img src="<?php echo $Ldir.$Lthefiles[$Li]; ?>" class="percent">
                </div>
            </a>
    <?php } 
?>
```

In the above code PHP is doing its job loading all the images from a nearby directory. The .adj class is formatting the `<div>` into a square and floating them all to the left so they tile the screen. It's also hiding the overflow so that no matter the dimensions all you see is a square.

My issue comes when trying to read the widths and heights of the images that are being loaded into that `<div>`. I want to have the image fit at a width or height of 100% depending on which is proportional to fill the square. Here's the jquery code I thought should work.

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $(".adj").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var imageWidth = $this.children("img").attr("width");
        var imageHeight = $this.children("img").attr("height");

        if (imageWidth < imageHeight){
            $this.addClass("aW");
        } else if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
            $this.addClass("aH");
        }
    }); 
});
```

I don't seem to be capturing an image width or height at all, with what I wrote above.

I'm using fullpage.js and [ilightbox.js](http://ilightbox.net/) which may be messing with my code, but I doubt it. I've also tried putting a modified version of this code inside the PHP `for` loop (without the jquery each function) and that doesn't work either. HELP!

[Here's a link for you.](http://www.crowellcreative.com/tackett)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the width and height in the css styling and not inline as `attributes`,
So attributes `width and height` are empty

```
$this.children("img").attr("width"); // .attr would not work
```

Should be

```
$this.children("img").css("width"); // .css is the method
```

And

```
$(window).load(function() { 

    $(".adj").each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       // when your referring same img multiple times, grab it in a variable
       var image = $this.children("img"); 
       var imgWidth =  image.width(); // or image.css("width")
       var imageHeight = image.height(); // or image.css("height")
        if (imageWidth < imageHeight){
           $this.addClass("aW");
        } else if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
           $this.addClass("aH");
       }
    }); 
});
```

**note** `.css()` gives in the `px`'.

Example `100px` even though you set the values in `pt or em etc`. After seeing your code since your comparing the values I would suggest `.width() and .height()`  as they return integer values and easy to compare

**jQuery documentation**

Note that `.width()` will always return the content width, regardless of the value of the CSS `box-sizing` property. As of jQuery 1.8, this may require retrieving the CSS width plus box-sizing property and then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when the element has `box-sizing: border-box`. To avoid this penalty, use `.css( "width" )` rather than `.width()`

Comment: thanks niko! i have one more question. There are two other image galleries that are hidden initially. Once I use jquery .fadeIn(); to unhide them I am not sure how to do the same thing to the images in those galleries. The $(window).load doesn't help in that case and the function I am trying to create doesn't seem to wait until the images are loaded.

Comment: I would consider using the `afterRender` callback of fullpage.js instead of using `$(window).load`.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. You are right, but I had some other issues due to the fact I was hiding the image galleries right as the document was ready. Now that I'm writing it down, it makes sense, but at the time I didn't realize that image height and width calculation wouldn't work unless the galleries were visible long enough for all the images to load. I gave myself the headache. Thanks to you both for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can try somethig like

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".adj").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var img = new Image();

        //Set Image source
        img.src = $this.children("img").attr("src");

        //Wait for image to be loaded.
        //Event will fire when image is loaded
        img.onload = function () {
            //Get Height and width
            var imageWidth = img.width;
            var imageHeight = img.height;
            if (imageWidth < imageHeight) {
                $this.addClass("aW");
            } else if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
                $this.addClass("aH");
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Note: I am not sure, this is a best practice

Comment: I would add an explanation as to the load event - because some browsers such as webkit wait until image is loaded to set dimensions